# Conditional probability where conditioned event is an inequality

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. My objective is to calculate the seemingly simple probability:

$$
\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y),
$$
where $a>0$ is a constant. Thus, from the definition of distribution functions this quantity is non-negative as long as $a\leq Y$. Expanding the above expression we have that

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y) 
&= \mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y\mid a\leq Y)\mathbb{P}(a\leq Y) + \underbrace{\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y\mid a\nleq Y)\mathbb{P}(a\nleq Y)}_{=0} \\
&= \mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq Y\mid a\leq Y)\mathbb{P}(a\leq Y) \\
&= (\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)-\mathbb{P}(X\leq a)) \mathbb{P}(a\leq Y) \\
&= (\mathbb{E}_Y[\mathbb{P}(X\leq y\mid Y=y)]-\mathbb{P}(X\leq a)) \mathbb{P}(a\leq Y).
\end{align}

Is this correct? My doubt comes from the fact that we condition on the event $a\leq Y$ rather than an event on the form $Z=z$.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions concerning the random variables like independence or so?

Comment: There is an error in how you go from the 2nd line to the 3rd line. How did you turn a conditional probability into a difference of 2 unconditional probabilities?

Comment: @user190080 $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @yurnero For two constants $a,b$ where $a<b$ and a random variable $Z$, I was applying the definition of a distribution function $\mathbb{P}(a\leq Z<b)=F_Z(b)-F_Z(a)=\mathbb{P}(Z<b)-\mathbb{P}(Z\leq a)$.

Comment: Sure, but there is a conditioning event, so you have $\Pr(a\leq X\leq Y|E)= \Pr[(X\leq Y)\cap(a\leq X)|E]$ where $E$ is the event $Y\geq a$. It's not clear how you get rid of $E$.